# Getting error when installing sh sample schema

Tags: oracle

I get error when I installing SH sample schema manually.

```
SP2-0606: Cannot create SPOOL file "$ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/sh_v3.log"
```

and `SP2-0310: unable to open file "__SUB__CWD__/sales_history/csh_v3.sql"`

If you know any step by step article or video please refer me.

This my steps. Can you help me where I do something wrong.

```
Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: sys as sysdba
Enter password:

Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> @?\demo\schema\sales_history\sh_main.sql

specify password for SH as parameter 1:
Enter value for 1: SH

specify default tablespace for SH as parameter 2:
Enter value for 2: users

specify temporary tablespace for SH as parameter 3:
Enter value for 3: temp

specify password for SYS as parameter 4:
Enter value for 4: SYS

specify directory path for the data files as parameter 5:
Enter value for 5: $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/

writeable directory path for the log files as parameter 6:
Enter value for 6: $ORACLE_HOME/demo/schema/log/

specify version as parameter 7:
Enter value for 7: v3

specify connect string as parameter 8:
Enter value for 8: XE
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you read & follow [Installing Sample Schemas](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00002)? Believe or not, it contains instructions how to [install the SH Schema](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/COMSC/installation.htm#COMSC00008)

Comment: This is my installing steps :

Comment: I added my steps to main post